# Slide down menu slides down but does not slide back up

Tags: jquery

I've made a dropdown menu using jQuery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('ul.menu li').mouseover( function() {
        $('ul', this).slideDown(200, function(){
        $('ul.menu li ul').mouseout( function() {
            $('ul', this).slideUp(200, function(){
                $(this).stop();
            });


        });
        });
    })
});
```

But after I do mouseover it doesn't hide.

Comment: `$('ul.menu li ul', this).mouseout( function() {`?

Comment: i dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because you're binding the mouseout function inside the mouseover function.

Try revising it like so:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('ul.menu li').mouseover(function() {
        $('ul', this).slideDown(200);
    });
    $('ul.menu li ul').mouseout( function() {
        $('ul', this).slideUp(200);
    });
});
```